# Browserify: how to aviod two instance of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browserify, commonjs

I'm trying to start using browserify in my project. I have bundled my js-script, and want to use vendor script in traditional way. But I've stuck some problem - there is a two instance of jQuery - one included with script tag - used by vendor scripts, and one exemplar <strike>to rule them all</strike> used for some script in bundle (that scripts can not be excluded).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/substack/factor-bundle. It's supposed to isolate all common code into a single file.